# Is Ubuntu compatible with UNIX applications?

Tags: compatibility

As somebody interested in backwards compatibility, I'm wondering if Ubuntu can natively run true-blue UNIX applications. Does this work?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Linux is not fully POSIX, and probably never will be. However, it does comply with many of the POSIX standards, and so many  POSIX-compliant applications may work (after recompiling, etc., of course).

Comment: @muru: I believe, that your comment is the answer to this question. Can you convert it to one, please?